# Column values are not updated when getting the values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 data frames: df, and df_final:

[image]

and

[image]

I want to make the values of column `x1` in `df_final` as `x1` in `df`. so I wrote the following loop:

```
for j in range(df.shape[0]):
   
    #for k in range(i+"_Edges_Count"):
            
            df_final[['x2']+['x1']].iloc[j]=df[['x2']+['x1']].iloc[j]
```

however, this does not change the values of `x1`. why is this?

Comment: There is no column with a label 'x2x1' in your dataframe, so you'll end up creating a new column. try this `df_final['x1'].iloc[j]=df['x1'].iloc[j]`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think:

`df_final['x1'] = df['x1']`

Comment: what if I want to change both coloums values? ```x1``` and ```x2```?

Comment: i: is the index of the column (each time)              

 ```df_final.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i]```